# ggplot2: How to curve small gaussian densities on a regression line?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, regression

I want to graphically show the assumptions of linear (and later other type) regression. How can I add to my plot small Gaussian densities (or any type of densities) on a regression line just like in this figure:

[image]

Comment: you might get some help from https://stats.stackexchange.com/ too

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13334294/903061) is pretty related. If you modified the `hist` in my answer to use `dnorm` instead of data, it might get you kinda close using base plots.

Comment: Did you want it to be based on the underlying data (even if simulated)? Or are you content to plot perfect little `dnorm`s at regularly spaced intervals?

Comment: I am thinking about perfect little 'dnorm'. In next step I want to do the same for GLM and GAMLSS models.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can compute the empirical densities of the residuals for sections along a fitted line.  Then, it is just a matter of drawing the lines at the positions of your choosing in each interval using `geom_path`.  To add theoretical distribution, generate some densities along the range of the residuals for each section (here using normal density).  For the Normal densities below, the standard deviation for each one is determined for each section from the residuals, but you could just choose a standard deviation for all of them and use that instead.

```
## Sample data
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(x=(x=runif(100, 0, 50)),
                  y=rnorm(100, 10*x, 100))

## breaks: where you want to compute densities
breaks <- seq(0, max(dat$x), len=5)
dat$section <- cut(dat$x, breaks)

## Get the residuals
dat$res <- residuals(lm(y ~ x, data=dat))

## Compute densities for each section, and flip the axes, and add means of sections
## Note: the densities need to be scaled in relation to the section size (2000 here)
dens <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$section), function(x) {
    d <- density(x$res, n=50)
    res <- data.frame(x=max(x$x)- d$y*2000, y=d$x+mean(x$y))
    res <- res[order(res$y), ]
    ## Get some data for normal lines as well
    xs <- seq(min(x$res), max(x$res), len=50)
    res <- rbind(res, data.frame(y=xs + mean(x$y),
                                 x=max(x$x) - 2000*dnorm(xs, 0, sd(x$res))))
    res$type <- rep(c("empirical", "normal"), each=50)
    res
}))
dens$section <- rep(levels(dat$section), each=100)

## Plot both empirical and theoretical
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", fill=NA, lwd=2) +
  geom_path(data=dens, aes(x, y, group=interaction(section,type), color=type), lwd=1.1) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=breaks, lty=2)
```

[image]

Or, just gaussian curves

```
## Just normal
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", fill=NA, lwd=2) +
  geom_path(data=dens[dens$type=="normal",], aes(x, y, group=section), color="salmon", lwd=1.1) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=breaks, lty=2)
```

[image]

Comment: this is great code, thanks!! I have one remark: Linear regression assumes homogeneity of variance. Those gaussian distributions must be forced to have equal variance but they dont. This can be misleading when the goal is to illustrate regression.