# Scatterplot with vertical histogram at every measurement ocassion

Tags: r, plot, graph, histogram, scatter-plot

I'm trying to make a scatterplot with vertical histogram/plot of the distribution at every measurement occasion. I can make the Confidence interval lines.

[image]

This is an example. How do I do this in R/ggplot2?

This is a package request specifically if there existed one.

If there isn't a package, how do I custom code this?

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31796083/496488) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a package in R that can do this. I tried with `ggplot2`, but couldn't overlay histograms onto a scatterplot.

I was able to overlay a basic scatterplot on a `ggplot` using `par(new=TRUE)`. I think you can probably adapt this code to change the margins and axes to get a better overlay and closer to what you want.

```r
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(1000),x=sample(c(1:4),1000,T),stringsAsFactors = F)

ggplot(df,aes(y)) + geom_histogram(alpha=0.2) + facet_grid(~x,) + coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal() + theme(axis.title = element_blank(),axis.text = element_blank(),
                          strip.text = element_blank())

par(new=T,mai=c(0,0,0,0))

plot(y~x,df)
```

[image]