# How to transpose or say flip the x and y axis in R

Tags: r

If I want to flip the histogram how would I do it. I tried google but couldn't find anything useful. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide us with a reproducible example. If you use `ggplot2`, you can use `coord_flip()` to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical Histogram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327489/vertical-histogram)

Comment: Are you sure you googled it right? Look at here: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-rotate-a-graph-reverse-and-flip-the-plot

Answer (score 2):

What you likely want is a barplot, as histogram cannot be flipped. See following for example of barplots:

http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html

Note last plot "flips" axis as you require:

```
par(las=2) # make label text perpendicular to axis
par(mar=c(5,8,4,2)) # increase y-axis margin.
counts <- table(mtcars$gear)
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution", horiz=TRUE, names.arg=c("3 Gears", "4 Gears", "5   Gears"), cex.names=0.8)
```

It uses the `horiz=TRUE` option to flip the axes.

To convert a histogram to barplot, do something similar to:

```
h <- hist(rnorm(1000))
barplot(h$counts, horiz = TRUE)
```