# Is there a way to go beyond the 200 row limit of layout() in R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot very long and thin barplots and am satisfied with layout(), where I have been using `matrix(1:200, 200, 1)` to define my plotting area. See example of such a plot in the attached image.

[example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3TJv.jpg)

I'd like to be able to do this where I have more than 200 datasets to plot.

> Error in layout(mat = matrix(1:201, 201, 1)) : 
>     too many rows in layout, limit 200

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like that limit is in C code, which makes it pretty hard to modify (i.e., want to re-compile R from source, with no guarantee that it will work). It may be possible to generate the plot without using `layout`... here's a *somewhat* similar example putting [vertical histograms on single plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13334294/903061)

Comment: Another option would be something like `Hmisc::subplot`. One big plot, and then each barplot is a subplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that `par(mfrow = c(300, 1))` does exactly what `layout(mat = matrix(1:300, 300, 1))` does, but without the limit warning. However, when I push the limit further I get a warning:

> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Are there ways around this? Particularly for exporting plots to files, plotting within rstudio is less important to me. Thanks again.

Comment: I can post a way to do a horizontal bar chart with ggplot2, but for the example data you're showing (single value), all plots start at the y-axis, unlike your example.

Comment: Are you running the code within a file plot device that is suitably large? e.g., `png("testplot.png", height = 9000, width = 1000); par(mfrow = c(300, 1))`?

Comment: I just picked a big number for the height - you should think about how many pixels you need per barplot and how many are taken up by the axis and labels. And I'm assuming you're also using `par` to adjust the margins to basically nothing for all the small figures.